# At dimming = 128, suddenly voltage goes up to 240 volt and then back to 0 volt

Tags: esp8266

**While using dimmer circuit with esp8266, at dimming = 128, suddenly voltage goes up to 240 volt and then back to 0 volt. at the output inductive load is connected like TABLE FAN** , it has not any type of adapter, its AC line device.

where, the dimming range is 0-128 . 
0=ON (no power clipping) means load should be ON.
128=OFF means load should be OFF.

1. Is this happens with dimmer circuit normally while load connected [TABLE FAN] or I am doing something wrong?
2. Also , can we use this value(128) for switching purpose? --means whenever we put the dimming=128 the load will be stay OFF,and power consumption stops towards load, as switch works.

i am newbie and trying esp8266 dimmer for first time.

here , the line voltage is 230-240 volts AC, 50Hz power supply .

[I am referring this circuit as it is and code also, only the change is dimming value taken using serial communication](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit/)

here i am using inductive load (TABLE FAN).

[image: this is circuit which is referred for dimmer]

`

```
  const int interruptPin = 14;
int AC_LOAD = 4;    // Output to Opto Triac pin
int dimming = 128;  // Dimming level (0-128)  0 = ON, 128 = OFF

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(AC_LOAD, OUTPUT);// Set AC Load pin as output
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), zero_crosss_int, RISING);  // Choose the zero cross interrupt # from the table above
}

//the interrupt function must take no parameters and return nothing
void zero_crosss_int()  //function to be fired at the zero crossing to dim the light
{
  // Firing angle calculation : 1 full 50Hz wave =1/50=20ms
  // Every zerocrossing thus: (50Hz)-> 10ms (1/2 Cycle)
  // 10ms=10000us
  // (10000us - 10us) / 128 = 75 (Approx) 

  int dimtime = (75 * dimming);  // For 60Hz =>65
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);    // Wait till firing the TRIAC
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
  delayMicroseconds(10);         // triac On propogation delay
  // (for 60Hz use 8.33) Some Triacs need a longer period
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);    // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the next zero crossing will swith it off) TRIAC
}


void loop()  {

   dimming = Serial.read(); // dimming value is taken from serial for 
                               dimming the load


}`
```

Comment: is it a 240 V fan or it has a AC/DC adapter working from 60 to 240 V?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of code, not just snippets. Minimal means you've stripped away irrelevant stuff, just leaving what's needed to show the problem. Complete means all the library names are shown, all the variable declarations, and all the function definitions – so people don't have to waste time guessing what you did or what you meant. Verifiable means it can be compiled and tested, allowing other people to test their theories about the problem

Comment: It is 240 v ac fan has not any adaptor

Answer (score 1):

```
int dimming = 128;  // Dimming level (0-128)  0 = ON, 128 = OFF
```

The code comments explicitly tell you that the range is 0-128; while non-trivial to do safely, digging out a scope to understand what exactly happens on overflow could be interesting (for example, it may skip alternate half cycles), but the obvious solution is to never command values outside that range, and *clamp* any out-of-range values which might be requested over the serial port to the limits.

Given that the timing is done unreliably in software, the precise phase behavior of your zero cross detector may be different than the original author's and the line frequency and pulse width constants may or may not be correct for your location, it's not really surprising that you are seeing 128 fall outside the limit of proper behavior rather than just within it.  Likely you want to be conservative in what you allow.

To avoid inconcistency, even better than clamping the maximum value, you may simply want to treat everything above a chosen delay limit as an absolute "off" by simply finishing the ISR immediately without firing the triac at all.  This may prove a lot simpler than trying to reliably find a delay limit that is "almost entirely" off without sometimes slipping over to firing right at the start of the next half cycle - and who really uses the "barely even on" range anyway?

Technically, depending on what the actual memory access width and alignment rules of the ESP8266 are, the sharing of a potentially non-atomic variable between the main and interrupt contexts could cause a **one time** glitch when it is changed (though even that is unlikely for your expected range of values, especially if you do the limiting before assignment to the shared variable). However, the atomicity concern can be simply remedied by using a `volatile unsigned char` (or more portably including `stdint.h` and using a `volatile uint8_t`) as the shared variable. The `volatile` keyword is used to require that the compiler actually calculate a variable that may not appear to be used, and actually store it in memory rather than merely cache it in a register.

It's worth noting that the software timed dimming, while somewhat portable is not particularly reliable, and may at high degrees of delay mean the processor spends almost all of its time in the ISR.  For this reason it is generally better to use a hardware timer for this purpose, however that then becomes more chip-specific.  If you are hoping to have things life WiFi running on your ESP8266 at the same time, you'll almost certainly want to move to a hardware timer to avoid glitching.

Ultimately it seems that the tutorial your are following is a poor one, such that doing a complete from-scratch reimplementation would be wise.  Additionally, mains-powered dimming circuits present many safety and reliability concerns even when driving a lightbulb - and it is by no means clear that your triac and snubber circuit are safe to use with an inductive load.  This is a challenging project, and not necessarily an *appropriate* one to attempt without deep experience.  You might want to consider using a DC fan PWM-controlled from a well-engineered low-voltage power supply instead.

Comment: While `volatile` is appicable in this particular case and MCU, it doesn't works if you are using an Arduino or if you need to change two or more related global variables in your ISR.

Comment: Untrue.  8-bit variables with a single writer as suggested here are atomic almost everywhere, including on ATmegas.  There are no linked variables here - the topic is already complex enough without getting sidetracked into situations that do not occur in it.

Comment: Due to amateur nature of most visitors to this site, it's much better to give an answer that cover the general case, even if not needed in this *particular case and MCU*. Others will read you answers and apply it blindly to other problems, with disastrous results. Better yet, post a sketch showing the OP the right way to do it.

Comment: Again, there is nothing specific to a given MCU here.  The poster got into their predicament by following a poorly written tutorial; getting out of it will require real thought to apply the explanations here.  This is not a project which can safely be approached by beginners - so the last thing it needs is untested code for someone to copy and paste to *other* situations where they do not understand that it does not apply.